# Getting a function from another class in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

So I am trying to just get the results on a page from a method I created in another class called selectColor();

I cant seem to figure out if I am doing this right.  Is there a special way to do this in PDO?

### connect.php - connection to database

```
<?php 
    //Initialize variables to make db connection
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbName = "stormfront_productions_test";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";

    try{
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbName;host=$host", $username, $password);
        echo 'Connection Successful';
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        echo $error;
    }




?>
```

### colors.class.php--all of the functions

```
  <?php



class colors {

//SELECT
    function selectColor()
    {
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM colors";
        require 'model/connect.php';
        $stmt = $pdo->query($sql); 
        $row =$stmt->fetchObject();
        echo "<table><tr><td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->color . "</td></tr></table>";
    }

//INSERT
    function insertColor($color){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO colors(color) VALUES (
            :color"; 
        require 'model/connect.php';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);                                 
        $stmt->bindParam(':color', $color);       
        $stmt->execute();
    }


//UPDATE
    function updateColor($color){
        $sql = "UPDATE colors SET color = :color; 
            WHERE id = :id";
        require 'model/connect.php';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);                                  
        $stmt->bindParam(':color', $color);       
        $stmt->execute();        
    }


//DELETE
    function deleteColor($color){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM colors WHERE color =  :color";
        require 'model/connect.php';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':color', $color);   
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}// END OF colors class
```

### colors.php--shows the results of the function selectColor();

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include 'model/functions/colors.class.php';
      include '/model/connect.php'?>

<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <?php
         $getConn = new $pdo();
    $showSelect = new colors();
    $showSelect->selectColor();
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read a bit about object-oriented programming. It is a bit more than just packing a few loosely related functions together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should create an object of class `colors` and only after that access it's method `selectColor()` :

```
 <body>
    <?php
    $showSelect = new colors();
    $showSelect->selectColor();
    ?>
</body>
```

PHP :

```
use PDO;

class colors {

private $pdo;

public function __construct(){
   $host = "localhost";
   $dbName = "stormfront_productions_test";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "root";

   try{
      $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbName;host=$host", $username, $password);
      echo 'Connection Successful';
   }catch(PDOException $e){
      $error = $e->getMessage();
      echo $error;
   }
}

//SELECT
function selectColor()
{
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM colors";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->query($sql); 
    $row =$stmt->fetchObject();
    echo "<table><tr><td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->color . "</td></tr></table>";
}

//INSERT
function insertColor($color){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO colors(color) VALUES (
        :color"; 
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);                                 
    $stmt->bindParam(':color', $color);       
    $stmt->execute();
}


//UPDATE
function updateColor($color){
    $sql = "UPDATE colors SET color = :color; 
        WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);                                  
    $stmt->bindParam(':color', $color);       
    $stmt->execute();        
}


//DELETE
function deleteColor($color){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM colors WHERE color =  :color";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':color', $color);   
    $stmt->execute();
}
} // END OF colors class
```

Comment: ok I am getting two notices now from the colors.class.php.  How can I correct this?
'code'( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in C:\xampp\htdocs\stormfront_productions_test\model\functions\colors.class.php on line 11
Call STack
2 0.0408 152376 colors->selectColor( ) ..\colors.php:16

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\stormfront_productions_test\model\functions\colors.class.php on line 11
Call Stack

2 0.0408 152376 colors->selectColor( ) ..\colors.php:16

Comment: @user3562189 : show your `require 'model/connect.php';` file.It means that  you should extend your `colors` class from db connection class or initiate an db connection object in your `colors` class.You can't just require a file.

Comment: Do i do this with an include or?  Can you show me what me an example or edit my code?

Comment: @user3562189 : As I said, I can do nothing until you post your `model/connect.php` file. You can use require on include - it doesn't really matter here - but you shouldn't forget about initiating object before using them in another class that doesn't extend this object's class.

Comment: see above in my code i have it requiring model/connect.php and it still throws the same errors.  I tried ../model/connect.php, ./model/connect.php, /model/connect.php, and model/connect.php and none seem to get rid of the errors, any idea?

Comment: @user3562189 : I really want to help you.But, however, we are talking in different languages, because you have a big lack of knowledge concerning OOP. The thing is that you should `include` or `require` your file with another class but you can't use it directly - at first you should create an object of this class, and only after that (as it is shown in my answer above) you can access it's public properties and methods.

Comment: Ok so what did I do in the code above because I did exactly as you are saying.  I creat an instance of the colors object.  And then I called the class.

Comment: @user3562189 : I am talking about your `colors` class - you don't initiate $pdo object.You should do it like I've done with `colors` class.

Comment: Like this  $getConn = new $pdo();

Comment: so i just pass in those paramaters that would be in my connect.php

Comment: i added the connect.php if it helps because its saying the $pdo() required at least one param.  What would that parameter be?

Comment: @user3562189:Ok.Just add `require 'model/connect.php';` everywhere before `$stmt = $pdo->query($sql); `.It will work out, but you really should look forward to obtaining base knowledge concerning OOP, because this approach is quite poor. Tip: write a wrapper for your pdo class and extend it from `colors` or initiate it in `colors` constructor or just initialize connection in `colors` class

Comment: Warning: PDO::__construct() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\stormfront_productions_test\colors.php on line 17



why am i getting this

Comment: OK so how would I do the colors.php file because its throwing those 2 errors again

Comment: @user3562189 : just copy my script.

Comment: Just did this is what i got

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method colors::query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\stormfront_productions_test\model\functions\colors.class.php on line 26`